# How to create a always visible Item in an ComboBox (DropDown)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

let's suggest we have a list of Names like this

```
        var list =new List<string>{"Abraham",
                                    "Alex",
                                    "Anna",
                                    "Babara",
                                    "Bea",
                                    "Lena",
                                    "Xena"};
```

and a combobx like this

```
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,50,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
              MaxDropDownHeight="50"/>
```

so you will only see 3 Items.

Now i want to have an Item `"Add Name"` that should always visible even after scrolling like shown in the picture below

[image]

So how can i achieve this? 
Is there already an easy way to do this which i miss on my research?

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: because the users of my app are brain-dead and they will forget there is such an element (and no i don't kidding)

Comment: You can try to replace `ControlTemplate` for your combobx or create usercontrol but i think is too difficult for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of it by editing the default template of Combobox. here are the steps what should be done.

1. Create duplicate template of Combobox.
2. find the popup    implemenatation.
3. in this find the itempresenter. implemantation.
4. Add new element over itemspresenter. and you will see that item always three.

hope you understand...

i will provide the sample template after some time.

[Combobox Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: i understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

the easy way would be to put a button near the combobox.

but if you want it the way you post, then you have to create a new controltemplate.